# Check if a list contains another list in Java

Tags: java

I have two Lists `List<List<Integer>>` a and b, as following:

```
a = [[120, 0], [121, 1], [122, 2], [123, 3], [124, 4], [125, 5]]
b = [[123, 3]]
```

I want a simple *method* that returns **true** or **false** if `b` contains an element of`a`.

I tried `b.contains(a)`, and `!Collections.disjoint(a, b)`, but to no avail. It doesn't seem to work with such deep lists.

EDIT: I'm posting the full code of my issue:

Some private variables:

```
private List<List<Integer>> processedCurrentCoordinate = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
```

And the main dish ( I want the first loop to be processed only if `HurdlefullCoordinatesList` is included inside `this.processedCurrentCoordinate`

```
public List<Integer> getNewData(int oldPositionX, int oldPositionY, int hasFood, List<List<Integer>> HurdlefullCoordinatesList) {

do {
  do {
    this.currentCoordinate.clear();
    this.processedCurrentCoordinate.clear();
    this.newPositionX = this.modelAnt.randomposition(oldPositionX);
    this.newPositionY = this.modelAnt.randomposition(oldPositionY);
    this.currentCoordinate.add(newPositionX);
    this.currentCoordinate.add(newPositionY);
    this.processedCurrentCoordinate.add(currentCoordinate);
  } while((Integer.valueOf(this.newPositionX).equals(Integer.valueOf(oldPositionX))) && (Integer.valueOf(this.newPositionY).equals(Integer.valueOf(oldPositionY))));
} while(HurdlefullCoordinatesList.contains(this.processedCurrentCoordinate));
```

Comment: Show us what you tried. This depends on the implementation of the `List` and the elements it contains.

Comment: Sorry, it seemed to be an automatic message. I'm updating the question.

Comment: Take a look at this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24035133/need-algorithm-for-fast-storage-and-retrieval-search-of-sets-and-subsets/24296615#24296615

Comment: [Here's an example that works.](https://ideone.com/AWfLiE) Remember that lists are ordered.

Comment: Thanks you, I studied it, but I can't understand it unfortunately. I'll try harder. Between, I updated my question.

Comment: If those are x, y coordinates in your inner lists, consider using `Point` class instead, with an appropriate `Point.equals()` method. That would reduce the problem to non-nested lists.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the inner list as parameter to contains and disjoint?